# Is a bialgebra with all group-like elements invertible a Hopf algebra?

Tags: hopf-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra

We know that in a Hopf algebra all group-like elements are invertible. Is the converse also true? Here is the precise formulation of my question :

Let $B$ be a bialgebra and $GLE$ = { $g \in B ~|~ g \neq 0, \Delta (g) = g \otimes g$ } the set of group-like elements. We know that this set is a monoid and that if B has an antipode, namely if $B$ is a Hopf algebra, then $GLE$ is a group.

Now, suppose that in the bialgebra $B$, every group-like element is invertible, does $B$ then have an antipode? (it would be easy to define an antipode $S: B \rightarrow B$ on $GLE$ by $S(g) = g^{-1}$, but what about the other elements?)

If there is a known counterexample, then what would be the extra-condition required to assure the existence of the antipode?

Comment: We really need a "Counterexamples in Hopf algebras" book...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is "no". A counterexample is given by Radford in Example 2 (p. 567) in the paper

$\quad\quad$[On Bialgebras which are simple Hopf Modules, Amer. Math. Soc. 80(1980),563-568](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-080-04/S0002-9939-1980-0587928-4/S0002-9939-1980-0587928-4.pdf)

He takes the coalgera $C = \mathbb{C}^\ast = Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Then the tensor algebra $T(C) = \mathbb{R} \oplus C \oplus (C \otimes C) \oplus ...$ is a cocommutative bialgebra that is no Hopf algebra and has $1$ as the only group-like element (thus forming a group).

Additional conditions that imply the existence of an antipode are (over fields)

1. Commutative bialgebras: That's a result of Takeuchi (can be found in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-23/issue-4/Free-Hopf-algebras-generated-by-coalgebras/10.2969/jmsj/02340561.full)), also reproved by Radford in the cited paper.
2. Cocummutative pointed bialgebras (see Sweedler's book "Hopf Algebras", Prop. 9.2.5).

Comment: I don't understand what is the bialgebra structure on $T(C)$.  How is the identification $C = \mathbb C^*$ used? Currently, it seems that $C$ is nothing more than a 2-dimensional vector space, in which case the standard cocommutative bialgebra structure on $T(C)$ makes it into the universal enveloping of the free Lie algebra on two generators. This is certainly Hopf.

Comment: I went and looked at the paper, and so can answer my question.  The algebra structure on $T(C)$ is the usual associative one.  The coalgebra structure, though, is not graded.  Rather, one gives $C^{\otimes n}$ the tensor coalgebra structure, and $T(C)$ is a direct sum of coalgebras.

Comment: Incidentally, there is a cute geometric interpretation of this construction. Let $X$ be a space. Then there is a monoid of "words in $X$", given by $T(X) = \bigcup_n X^{\times n}$, with "concatenation" as the monoid operation. This is clearly the construction here, because $\oplus$ of coalgebras is the categorical coproduct, and $\otimes$ is the categorical product. And because the category of cocommutative coalgebras is very much like a category of "spaces". The coalgebra $C$ corresponds to what the algebraic geometers call a "$\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C)$". The grouplikes ... 

Comment: ... in a coalgebra are precisely the "$\mathbb R$-points" of the corresponding space. So here the idea is that if $X$ has no $\mathbb R$-points, then $T(X)$ has only one $\mathbb R$-point (the identity).  On the other hand, if you test it against $X$-points, then you can tell it is not a group object. Just as cocommutative coalgebras are a type of "space", cocommutative Hopf algebras are precisely the "group objects" in the category of cocommutative coalgebras.

Comment: Theo, the tensorproduct of coalgebras has a natural coalgebra structure. By iteration $C \otimes \cdots \otimes C$ is a coalgebra. Then extend linearly to the direct sum. This construction is  sometimes called "the free bialgebra on C". 

Comment: Is something also known about finite-dimensional bialgebras with all group-like elements invertible?

Answer (score 5):

Sufficient conditions are known for the existence of an antipode on a bialgebra $A$ over a Commutative ring $R$ that do not assume that $A$ is either commutative or cocommutative. Assume that $A$ 
is graded, $A_i = 0$ for $i<0$, and $A_0$ is $R$-free.  Let $\epsilon\colon A\longrightarrow R$ be the counit (or augmentation).  Assume that $\epsilon^{-1}(1)$ is a group under the multiplication of  $A$.  For each grouplike element $g$, let $A_g = Rg \oplus \bar{A_g}$, where the set $\bar{A_g}$ of positive
degree elements of $A_g$ is the set of all elements $x\in A$ such that 
$$\psi(x) = x\otimes g + \sum x'\otimes x'' + g\otimes x$$
where the $x'$ and $x''$ are both of positive degree.  Assume that $A$ is the direct sum over $g\in GLE$ of the $A_g$.  Then $A$ has an antipode $\chi$.   If $A$ is commutative or cocommutative, 
then $\chi^2$ is the identity, but not in general otherwise.  The conditions are motivated by thinking 
about the homology of an $H$-space $X$ with coefficients in $R$.

Comment: Isn't the freeness assumption for $A_0$ already a consequence of $A=\oplus_g A_g$ and the invertibility of the group-likes, i.e. $A_0=R[G]$ where $G$ is the group of group-like elements ? 

Comment: So this generalizes the well-known fact that a connected $\mathbb{N}$-graded bialgebra is a Hopf algebra. Nice. 

Comment: Sure. I was specializing a more general result.  Let $C$ be a coalgebra, $A$ an algebra. $Hom_R(C,A)$ is an $R$-algebra. Let 
$G(C,A)$ be the submonoid of those $f$ such that $f\eta = \eta$
and $\epsilon f = \epsilon$.  One looks for sufficient conditions
on $C$ and $A$ for when $$G(C,A)$ is a group. Then one must assume $C_0$ is $R$-free, since the group hypothesis refers to $A$.

Comment: (I think) the end of @PeterMay's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86197/is-a-bialgebra-with-all-group-like-elements-invertible-a-hopf-algebra#comment222013_86283), just to have it here:  "… and for when $G(C, A)$ is a group.  Then one must assume $C_0$ is $R$-free, since the group hypothesis refers to $A$."