# Hopf algebra with a non-grouplike invertible element

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, bialgebras

What is an example of a Hopf algebra $(H,\Delta,\epsilon)$ containing an invertible element $h$ which is not grouplike: An element $h \in H$ such that
$$
\Delta(h) \neq h \otimes h\qquad\text{(not grouplike)}
$$
and such that there exists a $h^{-1} \in H$ with $hh^{-1} = h^{-1}h = 1$ (invertible).

Comment: Hae you looked at the group ring of a (finite) group?

Comment: Related (though clearly not the same question—this one seems much quicker to address, per @Tyrone's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384695/hopf-algebra-with-a-non-grouplike-invertible-element#comment979758_384695)):  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86197/is-a-bialgebra-with-all-group-like-elements-invertible-a-hopf-algebra .

Comment: Trivial example: scalar multiples of grouplikes are generally not grouplike.

Comment: @Tyrone: But in the group algebra every element is grouplike?

Comment: You seem to have just changed your question...

Comment: @Tyrone: Sorry about that, there was a typo - "not" was omitted!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $L$ be a finite-dimensional $p$-nilpotent restricted Lie algebra over a field of characteristic $p>0$ and consider its restricted enveloping algebra $u(L)$. Then the only group-like element of the Hopf algebra $u(L)$ is 1. On the other hand, every element of $u(L)$ that is not in the kernel of the counit is invertible.

Answer (score 10):

Let $G$ be any finite group. Then the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is, as an algebra, isomorphic to $\bigoplus_V \mathrm{End}(V)$, where the direct sum is over irreducible representations of $V$ of $G$. So the group of units of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is isomorphic to $\prod_V \mathrm{GL}(V)$. Only finitely many elements of this product come from the original group $G$. Any element of  $\prod_V \mathrm{GL}(V)$ not coming from $G$ is invertible but not group like.

To be concrete, let $G$ be the cyclic group $C_2$, with nontrivial element $g$. Then $a+bg$ is invertible as long as $(a+b)(a-b) \neq 0$, but $a+bg$ is group like only for $(a,b) = (1,0)$ and $(a,b) = (0,1)$.